# How do I download all files from a Google Drive folder with more than 50 files?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I cannot figure out how to write a program to download all files from a publicly accessible Google Drive folder, which has more than 1,000 of them.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/MY-PUBLICLY-ACCESSIBLE-FOLDER-ID?usp=drive_link'
gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True, remaining_ok=True, use_cookies=False)
```

But it only downloads 50 of the files.

Comment: Have you tried setting the flag like this `gdown.download_folder(my_google_drive_url, remaining_ok=True)`?

Comment: That downloads only 50 items from the folder.

Comment: a couple of questions: 1. are you okay with using other libraries, and 2. are the files you are downloading very big?

Comment: @Mark I'm fine with using other libraries. I'm trying to download around 1,000 images, mostly JPGs, with the largest ones being 250Kb or so.

Comment: @Generic_User_ID I think one approach could be to get the file URLs using `gdown`/another library, and then loop through those

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Google Drive API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python

Here is a script I have used in the past:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import io
import os

# Define the scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

# Obtain your Google credentials
def get_credentials():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    return creds

# Build the downloader
creds = get_credentials()
drive_downloader = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Replace 'FOLDER_ID' with your actual Google Drive folder ID
folder_id = 'FOLDER_ID'
query = f"Folder ID '{folder_id}'"
results = drive_downloader.files().list(q=query, pageSize=1000).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

# Download the files
for item in items:
    request = drive_downloader.files().get_media(fileId=item['id'])
    f = io.FileIO(item['name'], 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(f, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(f"Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.")

print(f"Downloaded {len(items)} files from the folder.")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Work Around:

Since `gdown`'s `download_folder` function doesn't care ***how many sub***folders of 50 files or fewer it has to download we can use the following function to organize the files in the folder you want to save in a new path by creating a `temp_folder` where all the files are moved into subfolders comprising of 50 files or fewer and then running the `gdown`'s `download_folder` function:

```
import os

def organize_folder_into_subfolders(path_to_original_folder, max_number_of_files_per_subfolder=50):
    '''Moves all files in a folder into newly created subfolders comprising of the max_number_of_files_per_subfolder or fewer'''
    files_in_folder = os.listdir(path_to_original_folder)
    if not path_to_original_folder.endswith('/'):
        path_to_original_folder += '/'
    temp_path_to_original_folder = path_to_original_folder + 'temp_folder'
    os.makedirs(temp_path_to_original_folder)
    subfolders_dict = {'temp_subfolder_0': []}
    os.makedirs(temp_path_to_original_folder + '/' + 'temp_subfolder_0')
    for _file_name in files_in_folder:
        if len(subfolders_dict['temp_subfolder_' + str(len(subfolders_dict) - 1)]) == max_number_of_files_per_subfolder:
            subfolders_dict['temp_subfolder_' + str(len(subfolders_dict))] = []
            os.makedirs(temp_path_to_original_folder + '/' + 'temp_subfolder_' + str(len(subfolders_dict) - 1))
        subfolders_dict['temp_subfolder_' + str(len(subfolders_dict) - 1)].append(_file_name)
    for _file_subfolder_path, _file_names in subfolders_dict.items():
        for _file_name in _file_names:
            os.rename(path_to_original_folder + _file_name, temp_path_to_original_folder + '/' + _file_subfolder_path + '/' + _file_name)
    return subfolders_dict
```

And then run the `download_folder` function:

```
import gdown
url = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OXV4qhFF_qJ8VqyrXpR7CzHDsToaqY_W?usp=drive_link'
gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True, use_cookies=False, remaining_ok=True)
```

And then if you want your original and new folders not organized as subfolders, we can use this function to "undo" or put the files back into the original and new folders and delete the temp subfolders:

```
import os

def undo_organize_folder_into_subfolders(path_to_original_folder, path_to_new_folder, subfolders_dict):
    '''Moves the files organized as subfolders back to the original & new folders and deletes subfolders'''
    if not path_to_original_folder.endswith('/'):
        path_to_original_folder += '/'
    if not path_to_new_folder.endswith('/'):
        path_to_new_folder += '/'
    temp_path_to_original_folder = path_to_original_folder + 'temp_folder'
    temp_path_to_new_folder = path_to_new_folder + 'temp_folder'
    for _file_subfolder_path, _file_names in subfolders_dict.items():
        for _file_name in _file_names:
            os.rename(temp_path_to_original_folder + '/' + _file_subfolder_path + '/' + _file_name, path_to_original_folder + _file_name)
            os.rename(temp_path_to_new_folder + '/' + _file_subfolder_path + '/' + _file_name, path_to_new_folder + _file_name)
        os.rmdir(temp_path_to_original_folder + '/' + _file_subfolder_path)
        os.rmdir(temp_path_to_new_folder + '/' + _file_subfolder_path)
    os.rmdir(temp_path_to_original_folder)
    os.rmdir(temp_path_to_new_folder)
```

And just make sure you have your current working directory set:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'
```

Comment: @Generic_User_ID I re-did my answer with a work around for the 50 file limit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are only able to download 50 files is that the `gdown` library, by default, uses the "cookie" method to access Google Drive files, and Google Drive has a limitation of 50 for direct downloads using cookies.
You can use the Google Drive API along to download 1000 files with the `google-api-python-client` library.

You'll need to install the `google-api-python-client` library to work with the Google Drive API and then, you'll need to create a project in the Google Developers Console, enable the Drive API, and create credentials (OAuth 2.0 client ID). Download the credentials as a JSON file and place it in your project directory.
Here's a Python script for the same

```py
import os
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

def authenticate(credentials_file):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(credentials_file)
    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def download_files(service, folder_id, output_dir):
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(
            q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents",
            spaces='drive',
            fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)',
            pageToken=page_token
        ).execute()

        for file in response.get('files', []):
            file_id = file['id']
            file_name = file['name']
            mime_type = file['mimeType']
            
            if mime_type == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                # If the file is a subfolder, recursively call the function to download its contents.
                download_files(service, file_id, os.path.join(output_dir, file_name))
            else:
                # If the file is not a folder, download it.
                request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
                file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, file_name)
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(request.execute())

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials_file = 'path_to_your_credentials.json' 
    folder_id = 'MY-PUBLICLY-ACCESSIBLE-FOLDER-ID'
    output_directory = 'path_to_output_directory'

    if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)

    service = authenticate(credentials_file)
    download_files(service, folder_id, output_directory)
```

please change the file paths accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this error, where i needed to download around 1800 images from google drive, and gdown allowed me only to download 50.

I am not experienced in programming, and i dont know if my solution would work in other situations, but google drive limits the download to 50, and it has some sort of link to cookies.

After i encountered this issue, i started to research and found that gdown was a dead end. After ending my research, i gave my gdown script a last try, and it started downloading files and again stopped at 50.

After some trail and error, i reached the conclusion, that google drive limits downloads to 50 by using cookies(i dont know if that is the right terminology) BUT those cookies reset themselves after approximately 40 minutes. So i imported time, and added a delay of 60 seconds after 1 picture is downloaded. So before reaching the cookie limit of 50 pictures, because of the delay the cookies slowly reset themselves, and i downloaded my whole subfolder of 153 pictures without any issue.

Hope this helps someone!

```
import gdown
import os
import shutil
import time

names = open("names.txt", "r")
names = names.read()
names = names.split("\n")

pictures = open("pictures.txt", "r")
pictures = pictures.read()
pictures = pictures.split("\n")

for i in range(len(pictures)):
    sp = pictures[i]
    url = sp  ###

    sp = sp.split("/")
    sp = sp[3]
    sp = sp.split("=")
    sp = sp[1]
    id = sp  ###
    prefix = "https://drive.google.com/uc?/export=download&id="

    gdown.download(prefix + id)

    for file in os.listdir():
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if file == ".idea" or file == "main.py" or file == "names.txt" or file =="pictures.txt" or file == "venv":
            continue
        if str(ext) == ".jpg" or ".png" or ".jpeg":
            timg = str(name) + str(ext)
            os.rename(timg, str(names[i]) + str(ext))
            shutil.move(str(names[i]) + str(ext), "final pictures")
    print(i)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Please add code

Comment: @Mark code added you can check

Comment: it's great! thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Since there is limitation of max 50 files for gdown library, you might want to check out something like ZDrive library.

It is pretty simple if you check it out. And since you know your folder Id, it should be easy job to use a downloader from the library.

Supporting the same idea as the gdown library it can be coded in few code lines (based on library documentation):

```
from zdrive import Downloader
output_directory = "/home/abhinav/Documents"
d = Downloader()
folder_id = 'XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ'
d.downloadFolder(folder_id, destinationFolder=output_directory)
```

Comment: Most of the image files this downloads are 0 bytes. I do not know why.

Comment: It might be related to the extra step you might need to look into. Check out library github page - https://github.com/ab-anand/ZDrive
And section "4.1 Initial Setup" probably needs to be taken into consideration. I cannot test this one out from my work machine due to blocked GDrive access.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers above and that may be enhanced for them. The reason why your code only downloads 50 of the files is that the `gdown` library has a limit of 50 files for direct downloads using cookies. To download more than 50 files.

Start with `install oogle-api-python-client`

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2 google-auth google-auth-oauthlib pickle5
```

then you can use this code

```
import io
import os
import pickle
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these SCOPES, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Get the folder ID from the URL.
    url = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_URL'  # Replace with your Google Drive URL
    folder_id = url.split("/")[-1]

    # Create a directory to store the downloaded files.
    download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "downloaded_files")
    if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
        os.mkdir(download_dir)

    # Download the files.
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = drive_service.files().list(q="'{}' in parents".format(folder_id),
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute()
        files = response.get('files', [])
        for file in files:
            request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file['id'])
            fh = io.FileIO(os.path.join(download_dir, file['name']), 'wb')
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print(f'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This downloads 100 files.

Comment: Because, it is not deal with the next page, Now you can try it.